# binary search - if I add or subract "1" from the middle of the list, do I get the first number on the left of the middle one or a numerical value?

Tags: c

My doubt occurs inside the while loop. What am I doing when I add "1" to the minimum and maximum of the list -- am I moving to the left/right of the numbers on the list or changing values numerically? Thanks!

```
bool search(int value, int values[], int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        return false;
    }

    // beginning and final portions
    int min = 0;
    int max = n - 1;

    // middle variable
    int mid = n / 2;

    // this massive number will be useful to guarantee that the search function 
    // can handle incredibly large arrays
    const int MAX = 65536;

    while (n > 0) {
        if (value > value[middle]) {
            min = middle + 1;
        } else
        if (value < value[middle]) {
            max = middle - 1;
        } else
        if (value == value[middle]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt it compiles. `value[middle]` should complain: The array is named `values`. To answer your question: Adding a number to an array index moves the index. However, I think your loop is infinite.

Comment: The assignment operator (`=`) modifies the value of its left-hand operand, either `max` or `min` in this case.  These are not elements of your `value` array, but rather *indexes* of particular significant values.

Comment: This might be a silly question but how do I know that min and max are indexes of the array rather than simple variables? @Elyasin

Comment: @JohnBollinger if you can help as well, thanks for the two of you!

Comment: @gcampeao You said so in your code: `// beginning and final portions` - an index is a simple variable, of type integer. To be honest with you, I suggest you try to learn by doing a tutorial or reading a book about the C programming language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's think your value array is like: 1 2 5 6 9 so min=1,max=9,mid=5; now suppose your value is 7 then `if (value > value[middle]){min = middle + 1;}` this block will be active.

Now look as we are sure that our value is greater than middle value so we can increase our minimum value to be (mid+1)th index of value array.

same applies when it is smaller.  so you are actually moving min/max index of value array. Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

Your function is broken in many respects:

- it does not implement binary search
- `MAX` is not *massive*, and it is not even used anywhere
- `middle` is undefined, and it is not modified in the loop.
- `value > value[middle]` should probably be `value > values[mid]`...

Here is a simple correct implementation (borrowed from Matt Timmermans):

```
bool search(int value, int values[], size_t n) {
    size_t pos = 0;
    size_t limit = n;

    while (pos < limit) {
        size_t middle = pos + ((limit - pos) >> 1);

        if (values[middle] < value)
            pos = middle + 1;
        else
            limit = middle;
    }
    return pos < n && values[pos] == value;
}
```